# VB6: Shell invalid arguments

Tags: shell, vb6, arguments

I went through all related answers, but I still could not solve my problem.

I would like to shell the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\my application\application\bin\app.exe background
```

As one can see, there are spaces in the path, and there is an argument.

I tried just anything I could image regarding quotes, but I just don't find the right escaping.

Could anybody help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How exactly did things you tried not work? What have you observed that led you to conclude its "wrong escaping"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the path and stick the argument on the end:

```
ret = shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\my application\application\bin\app.exe"" background", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: How so? `ret = Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"" c:\windows\win.ini", vbNormalFocus)` works fine for me

Comment: I don't know why, sorry.

Comment: do you use the correct double quotes? ... some systems convert the starting double quotes to inverted ones ... please post the code you are using (just copy and paste, dont change it)